# Is it possible to collect an unexploded exploding pod?

Tags: wasteland-2

In the Ag Center (went-there-first version), Kathy Lawson wants me to collect an exploding pod, but this doesn't seem to be possible because the left-click action on the pod plants is always to attack it.  Outdoorsman skill can't be applied.  The "Curious Pod" item found as a drop from some animals apparently isn't the relevant kind of pod, as it does not satisfy Kathy.  It is actually possible to collect a pod, rather than collecting ten exploded pod fragments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No.** I believe that it is not possible to collect an unexploded pod in the Release Version.

The text asking you to do so is likely a hold-over from back when it was going to be possible, and back when the skill Silent Move was still in the beta.

This skill was removed from the game because they felt it was too hard to make it not game-breaking.

> Silent Move has been out of the beta for a while, and it is in fact
> permanently cut. It became too easy to break game triggers, which
> would in turn-break the game.
>
> https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/inxile/wasteland-2/posts/895618

Answer (score 2):

Not in the beta/alpha stage. They have not yet implemented a stealth system, so you cannoy stealthily walk up to the pod without it exploding in the first place...